# preprocessor constant overflow?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I use Arduino Uno (16 bit [int](http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/Int) ) and:

```
#define DT 49
#define DT_MICRO ((DT) * 1000)
...
while (val<DT_MICRO){/*something*/}
```

Which give

```
49
-16536
```

if I print them using `Serial.print(DT);`. Why? I'd expect 49000. Why is there a negative number? Same happens if I use (within the code) `Serial.print(DT*1000)`.

Using

```
DT 49L
and DT_MICRO (DT*1000L)
```

works like expected. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: 16-bit compiler perhaps.  49000 == 0xbf68 == -16536.  Use 1000L instead.  print() needs work either way.

Comment: Or `printf("%d", (short)DT_MICRO);`, or a dozen other reasons (including [nasal demons](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons) and solar flares). No way to tell.

Comment: Now that you've accepted an answer, can you please update your question to show exactly *how* you printed the value? It would be helpful to future readers (and satisfy my curiosity). Also, what platform are you using, and how big is type `int` on that system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than in `#if` directives, the preprocessor does not perform arithmetic, only textual substitution. Any occurrence of `DT_MICRO` in your code is replaced by the sequence `((49) * 1000)` before the later phases of the compiler see it.

The constants `49` and `1000` are of type `int`. (More generally, an integer constant is of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, depending on its value; `49` and `1000` are guaranteed to fit in an `int`, so that's their type.)

Because of that, the expression `((49)*1000)` is also of type `int`. For expressions (as opposed to constants), the type isn't affected by the value. If 49,000 is too big to fit in an `int`, then the expression overflows.

The type `int` is required to be at least 16 bits, with an upper bound of at least 32767. It's more common these days for it to be 32 bits, with an upper bound of 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1). So if `int` is 16 bits, then `DT_MICRO` has undefined behavior, but will most likely evaluate to `-16536`, which is what you're seeing. If `int` is 32 bits, then `DT_MICRO` evaluates to exactly `49000`.

As for why you're seeing that negative value, you haven't given us enough information to be sure. You say you "print" the value, but how? The correct way to print it would be:

```
printf("%d\n", DT_MICRO);
```

but there are a number of other things you could have done.

If you need to be sure that `DT_MICRO` is of a type big enough to hold its value, you can change your definitions to:

```
#define DT 49L
#define DT_MICRO (DT * 1000L)
```

(note that the extra parentheses around `DT` aren't necessary as long as `DT` was defined properly). This causes it to be of type `long`, which is at least 32 bits, and you can print it with:

```
printf("%ld\n", DT_MICRO);
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor doesn't have the ability to interpret constants as one type or another, it can only do lexical replacements... so your program would be exactly the same as:

```
print(49*1000)
```

and those are treated as naked constants in the .c file so without knowing what the prototype of `print()` is, I can't really help further except to point you away from the pre-processor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the number is negative is that you are using 16 bit signed math. The largest positive number you can represent is 32767. Anything larger than that is considered a negative number. If you want to learn more about signed integer math there are a lot of sources online.

To calculate larger values you will need to use a different variable type.